# Reduce a nested list with varying length

Tags: r, list, reduce

Say i have a list:

```
  mylist=list(list(data.frame(a=3,b=2,c=4),data.frame(d=5,e=6,h=8),data.frame(k=2,e=3,b=5,m=5)),
              list(data.frame(a=32,b=22,c=42),data.frame(d=5,e=63,h=82),data.frame(k=2,e=33,b=5,m=5)),
              list(data.frame(a=33,b=21,k=41,c=41),data.frame(d=5,e=61,h=80),data.frame(k=22,e=3,b=5,m=5)))
```

Then I try to get a new list by `cbind` each element of the list, for example cbind `mylist[[1]][[1]]`with`mylist[[2]][[1]]`and`mylist[[3]][[1]]`

The function:

```
newlist=lapply(seq_along(mylist[[1]]), function(x){    
    newlist=Reduce("cbind",c(mylist[[1]][x],mylist[[-1]][x]))
    return(newlist)

})

I get:
Error in mylist[[-1]] : attempt to select more than one element
```

But the lapply works if the list is only:

```
mylistshort=mylist[-3]
```

The desired result is:

```
[[1]]
  a b c  a  b  c a  b  k  c
1 3 2 4 32 22 42 33 21 41 41

[[2]]
  d e h d e  h  d e  h
1 5 6 8 5 63 82 5 61 80

[[3]]
  k e b m k e  b m k  e m
1 2 3 5 5 2 33 5 5 22 3 5
```

So how do I reduce a list with length bigger then 2?
Best Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another idea:

```
.mapply(cbind, mylist, NULL)
#[[1]]
#  a b c  a  b  c  a  b  k  c
#1 3 2 4 32 22 42 33 21 41 41
#
#[[2]]
#  d e h d  e  h d  e  h
#1 5 6 8 5 63 82 5 61 80
#
#[[3]]
#  k e b m k  e b m  k e b m
#1 2 3 5 5 2 33 5 5 22 3 5 5
```

**EDIT:** *some comments*

You 're, basically, looking for a "vectorised" `cbind`. You can use a `for` loop for this, but R has a built-in "vectorisation" tool: `mapply` (not neccessarily faster, but cleaner). You could use `mapply`, for a specific number of arguments, like this:

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) cbind(x, y, z), mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], mylist[[3]])
```

But, you could, also, pass a "variable-length arguments" (`...`) to make it more practical:

```
mapply(function(...) cbind(...), mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], mylist[[3]])
```

`cbind` is built to know how to handle `...` arguments:

```
mapply(cbind, mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], mylist[[3]])
```

This, still, is not flexible because you'll have to specify each argument since `mapply` accepts only `...`. `do.call` is handy for cases where you have a function's arguments in a "list":

```
do.call(mapply, c(cbind, mylist))
```

R, has a dotted `mapply` that accepts its `...` arguments as a list, looks cooler, and can replace `do.call`:

```
.mapply(FUN = cbind, dots = mylist, MoreArgs = NULL)
```

Comment: Great answer! Learned something new:)

Answer (score 3):

You do the following (usind `Reduce`) as Ananda Mahto suggested:

```
myfun <- function(x) Reduce(cbind,x)
apply(do.call(cbind, mylist), 1, myfun)
```

My original answer (including `data.table`)

```
require(data.table)
setDT(mylist)
myfun <- function(x) Reduce(cbind,x)
apply(mylist,1, myfun)
```

Result:

```
> apply(mylist,1, myfun)
[[1]]
  a b c  a  b  c  a  b  k  c
1 3 2 4 32 22 42 33 21 41 41

[[2]]
  d e h d  e  h d  e  h
1 5 6 8 5 63 82 5 61 80

[[3]]
  k e b m k  e b m  k e b m
1 2 3 5 5 2 33 5 5 22 3 5 5
```

Comment: Curious, what's the purpose of using `data.table` in your answer?

Comment: @Floo0 The `setDT` version is innovative.  +1

Comment: To be honest:  I did and do not know how i can have a `data.frame`, `matrix`, `array` or something similar that contains `data.frame`'s as entries. `data.table` can do this. This is why i used `setDT`.
Maybe there is a more elegant solution...

Comment: P.S.: Have a look at `mylist` after `setDT` to see what i mean

Comment: @Floo0, if you want to do this in base, you can do `apply(do.call(cbind, mylist), 1, myfun)`.

Comment: Thanks for this explaination. Just added it to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses a good ol' fashioned `do.call()` instead of `Reduce()`.

```
lapply(
    seq_along(mylist), 
    function(ii) do.call(cbind, vapply(mylist, "[", list(1), ii))
)

# [[1]]
# a b c  a  b  c  a  b  k  c
# 1 3 2 4 32 22 42 33 21 41 41
# 
# [[2]]
# d e h d  e  h d  e  h
# 1 5 6 8 5 63 82 5 61 80
# 
# [[3]]
# k e b m k  e b m  k e b m
# 1 2 3 5 5 2 33 5 5 22 3 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks, beatiful... Thought I could use reduce though... I will accept you answer if no one else will find a `Reduce` solution.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Well it does not, thought that there was a solution with `Reduce`...

Comment: `Reduce()` is nice, but it can be slower than other functions if you're not actually using it to perform the tasks it was designed for

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `unlist` as follows:

```
un_mylist <- unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE)
ind <- lapply(seq_along(mylist), seq, to = length(un_mylist), by = length(mylist))
myfun <- function(ind, x){
  Reduce(cbind,x[ind])
}
lapply(ind, myfun, x = un_mylist)
```

This approach assumes that all nested lists do have the same length:
`sapply(mylist, length)`